# How to force VoiceOver Focus on some element, in OS X?

Tags: macos, cocoa, accessibility

I want to change the voiceOver focus to another element in my cocoa app (in os x)
Should it be done with notification by using NSAccessibilityPostNotification or another mechanism? 
It's not so clear....

If to make some analogy to iOS I want to do, what the next code do in iOS:
UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification, myAccessibilityElement);

Answer (score 0):

Everything I tried using `NSAccessibilityPostNotification` was a failure.

But turns out VoiceOver will follow the **window's first responder**, so you simply need to do that, as you would do without considering any accessibility feature:

```
someWindow.makeFirstResponder( accessibilityElement )
```

or in Objective-C:

```
[ someWindow makeFirstResponder: accessibilityElement ];
```

VoiceOver focus will change too.

I think it's still a good idea to investigate accessibility notifications to let the user know why the change happened.

*Note: this was tested on macOS 10.15 Catalina.*

Comment: Hey is there some other way to shift the VO focus? makeFirstResponder doesn't seems to work for me.